MinGW - Unable to build GRPC on Windows
This is the build command I run:
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug --target grpc -- -j 30 VERBOSE=1

This is my main CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Vibranium-Engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE LEGACY)
set(gRPC_INSTALL ON CACHE BOOL "Enable gRPC install")
set(ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD ON CACHE BOOL "Propagate C++ standard to abseil-cpp")
set(protobuf_MODULE_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(RECASTNAVIGATION_DEMO OFF CACHE BOOL "Build demo" FORCE)
set(RECASTNAVIGATION_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "Build tests" FORCE)
set(RECASTNAVIGATION_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "Build examples" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if(APPLE)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0")
    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0/include")
    set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0/lib")
endif ()

find_package (OpenSSL REQUIRED)

set(ENV{FORCE_OPENSSL} "1")
set(gRPC_SSL_PROVIDER "package" CACHE STRING "SSL library provider")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/macros)

file(GLOB_RECURSE Source_Files
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Configuration/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Crypto/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Database/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/DataSchemas/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dynamic/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Component/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Component/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Profiler/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Profiler/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Signal/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Http/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Memory/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Logging/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Logging/*.cxx
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Networking/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Threading/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Utils/*.cpp
)

add_library(Vibranium-Engine SHARED ${Source_Files})
option(BUILD_RECAST_DEMO "Build the RecastDemo target" OFF)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tests)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Vibranium)

get_target_property(Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS protobuf::libprotobuf INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message ("PROTOBUFF INCLUDE: ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
target_include_directories(Vibranium-Engine PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/stb
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/glew/include
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/rapidjson/include
        ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${FLATBUFF_INC}
        ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(Vibranium-Engine PUBLIC
        boost
        curl
        fmt
        ImGui
        ImGuizmo
        mysql
        utf8cpp
        tabulate::tabulate
        gtest_main
        sentry::sentry
        b_stacktrace::b_stacktrace
        xmem
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        DebugUtils
        Detour
        DetourCrowd
        DetourTileCache
        Recast
        OpenSSL::SSL
        OpenSSL::Crypto
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
        ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}
        glew
        glfw
        grpc
        grpc++
        grpc++_reflection
        grpc++_unsecure
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        flatbuffers
)



if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources)
    message(STATUS "New ${AppName} Engine Resources folder will be created in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources/")
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Resources DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine)
else()
    file(GLOB Resources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Resources/*)
    file(COPY ${Resources} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources)
endif()


set_target_properties(
        Vibranium-Engine
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
)

install(TARGETS Vibranium-Engine LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

This is the error I get:
[  8%] Built target upb
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/simplify.cc.obj
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/stringpiece.cc.obj
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/simplify.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\simplify.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\simplify.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\re2\simplify.cc
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_casefold.cc.obj
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_groups.cc.obj
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ar.exe" qc libabsl_civil_time.a CMakeFiles/civil_time.dir/internal/cctz/src/civil_time_detail.cc.obj
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/rune.cc.obj
[  8%] Linking C static library libaddress_sorting.a
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe" libabsl_civil_time.a
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\address_sorting.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/stringpiece.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\stringpiece.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\stringpiece.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\re2\stringpiece.cc
[  8%] Built target int128
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/tostring.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\tostring.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\tostring.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\re2\tostring.cc
[  8%] Built target civil_time
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_casefold.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\unicode_casefold.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\unicode_casefold.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\re2\unicode_casefold.cc
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_groups.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\unicode_groups.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\re2\unicode_groups.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\re2\unicode_groups.cc
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\address_sorting.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/rune.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\util\rune.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\util\rune.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\util\rune.cc
[  8%] Building CXX object dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/strutil.cc.obj
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe" -DGIT_BRANCH=\"v3\" -DGIT_COMMIT_HASH=\"8e1bce410\" -DGIT_RELEASED_ON="\"2024-06-03 16:52:40 +0300\"" -DGIT_VERSION=\"5822\" -DNOMINMAX -DSTRICT -DUNICODE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_UNICODE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x600 @CMakeFiles/re2.dir/includes_CXX.rsp -fPIC  -g -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -MD -MT dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/third_party/re2/CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/strutil.cc.obj -MF CMakeFiles\re2.dir\util\strutil.cc.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\re2.dir\util\strutil.cc.obj -c V:\Vibranium-Core\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2\util\strutil.cc
[  8%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_spinlock_wait.a
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\base && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\spinlock_wait.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ar.exe" qc libaddress_sorting.a CMakeFiles/address_sorting.dir/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting.c.obj CMakeFiles/address_sorting.dir/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting_posix.c.obj CMakeFiles/address_sorting.dir/third_party/address_sorting/address_sorting_windows.c.obj
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe" libaddress_sorting.a
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
[  8%] Built target address_sorting
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\base && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\spinlock_wait.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ar.exe" qc libabsl_spinlock_wait.a CMakeFiles/spinlock_wait.dir/internal/spinlock_wait.cc.obj
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe" libabsl_spinlock_wait.a
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
[  8%] Built target spinlock_wait
[  8%] Linking CXX static library libabsl_time_zone.a
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\time && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\time_zone.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\abseil-cpp\absl\time && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\time_zone.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ar.exe" qc libabsl_time_zone.a CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_fixed.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_format.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_if.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_impl.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_info.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_libc.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_lookup.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/time_zone_posix.cc.obj CMakeFiles/time_zone.dir/internal/cctz/src/zone_info_source.cc.obj
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe" libabsl_time_zone.a
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
[  8%] Built target time_zone
[  8%] Linking CXX static library libre2.a
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -P CMakeFiles\re2.dir\cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /d V:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug\dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\re2 && "V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\re2.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ar.exe" qc libre2.a CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/bitstate.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/compile.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/dfa.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/filtered_re2.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/mimics_pcre.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/nfa.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/onepass.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/parse.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/perl_groups.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/prefilter.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/prefilter_tree.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/prog.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/re2.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/regexp.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/set.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/simplify.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/stringpiece.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/tostring.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_casefold.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/re2/unicode_groups.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/rune.cc.obj CMakeFiles/re2.dir/util/strutil.cc.obj
"V:\Program Files\CLion 2024.1.2\bin\mingw\bin\ranlib.exe" libre2.a
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
[  8%] Built target re2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'V:/Vibranium-Core/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2128: dep/Vibranium-Engine/dep/grpc/CMakeFiles/grpc.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:305: grpc] Error 2

This code I can compile on both Linux and MacOS. But it can't be compiled on Windows.
Why is that?

You may want to use msys2 to provide your MinGW and have pacman install grpc for you: https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-grpc

I don't see anything in the error message that is helping me to determine the problem.

Error 2 is probably ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, but it isn't obvious to me what wasn't found. If you try to build again without cleaning is the error any clearer? I'd hope it would skip rebuilding wat already exists and perhaps narrow down the issue.

Here is what I see when I try to build: https://pastebin.com/0Y2ijudh I also tried msys2  @drescherjm and it gives the same error.
When I click on Makefile:305 from the error sentance mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:305: grpc] Error 2 it brings me to the end of Makefile which have content like this: https://pastebin.com/EeGjFcC5

dep\Vibranium-Engine\dep\grpc\third_party\cares\cares\src\lib\CMakeFiles\c-ares.dir\build.make:976: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.

@RetiredNinja why is that? When I navigate to that dir it is not empty.

Did you look at that line in the file?
